# Meteor: How to get name of input based on type?

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I'm trying to change an input's class based on a `Session` value. Right now I have the code below but I want to condense it:

```
<template name="filterDate">
    <input type="submit" name="setToday" class="filterbutton {{day}}" value="Today" />
    <input type="submit" name="setWeek" class="filterbutton {{week}}" value="This Week" />
</template>
```

and

```
Template.filterDate.helpers({
    'day': function(){
        if(Session.equals('filterDatebtn',"setToday")){
            return "btn-on";
        }
    },
    'week': function(){
        if(Session.equals('filterDatebtn',"setWeek")){
            return "btn-on";
        }
    }
});
```

I want to make something like:

```
Template.filterDate.helpers({
    'on': function(){
        var name = this.name;
        if(Session.equals('filterDatebtn', name)){
            return "btn-on";
        }
    }
});
```

But I am unable to get the name of the input. I've also tried `$('input[type=submit]').attr("name")`  and  `$(this).attr('name')`

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: where is the code to set the `Session` ?

Comment: Your `$('input[type=submit]')` returns an array of matches... not a single match.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly different approach where you just pass in the input button type as the parameter to your helper.

html:

```
<template name="filterDate">
  <input type="submit" name="setToday" class="filterbutton {{on "day"}}" value="Today" />
  <input type="submit" name="setWeek" class="filterbutton {{on "week"}}" value="This Week" />
</template>
```

js:

```
Template.filterDate.helpers({
  'on': function(name){
    if(Session.equals('filterDatebtn', name)){
      return "btn-on";
    }
  }
});
```

Note that `this` in a helper is the *data context* not any kind of DOM element.